# How do you parse simple command line options with Perl?

Tags: perl

When i run a Perl file with command line input it should update a field in the table.

For example

```
perl function_impl.pl --address_only
```

if it receives the input parameter `--address_only` then t should update only address field in the db of that Perl script.How to implement this.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Which part gives you trouble? command line options? DB updates?

Comment: Also, how will you supply update value?

Comment: Also, of the 2 questions people answered for you, you didn't upvote or accept even a single answer. Keep that up and people will not be very eager to answer your questions.

Comment: You also never answered my questions about update value and DB details.

Answer (score 11):

[Getopt::Long](http://search.cpan.org/~jv/Getopt-Long-2.38/lib/Getopt/Long.pm) is a very common and very easy way in Perl to parse command line parameters.

```
my %args = ();
GetOptions (\%args, 'address_only');       # will store true value in $args{address_only}

if ($args{address_only}) {
    # Update address
}
```

Please show us the code you use to update the table so we can provide assistance with that part if you need it.

Also, how will you supply the update value? From your example you won't be supplying it via command line, so I assume it's hard-coded? If you want to supply on command line, change the above code to accept values for the parameter:

```
my %args = ();
GetOptions (\%args, 'address_only=s'); # will store address value in $args{address_only}
# Usage: function_impl.pl --address_only joe@myaddress.com
```

As a trivial example, you can build "SET" part of update statement:

```
my $set_fields = 0;
if ($args{address_only}) {
    $set_fields .= ", " if $set_fields; # comma separate if >1 set
    $set_fields .= qq[address = "$args{address_only}"];
    # or $set_fields .= qq[address = "$hardcoded_address"];
}
# Build the full UPDATE SQL statement using $set_fields
# Execute SQL statement
```

Answer (score -4):

If your script accepts zero or one argument you can do:

```
if( $#ARGV == 0 ) {     # one argument passed
        if($ARGV[0] eq '--address_only') {
                # --address_only passed
        } else {
                # something else passed
        }
}elsif( $#ARGV == -1 ) { # no argument passed

}else{                   # more than one arg passed

}
```

Comment: `@ARGV` manual parsing is not scalable at all. A CPAN module for option parsing (Getopt::Std or Getopt::Long) should always be used instead to provide scalability (never mind readability).

Comment: Why check `$#ARGV` when you really want the number of arguments? That's available in `@ARGV`, with no off-by-one problems.